# how do you get java or kotlin source from a react native apps?

Tags: react-native, mobile

Can we extract source code from an apk that built with react-native framework?. i've tried using dex2jar and apktools and cant seem to find anything related to source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing would prevent Apktool or dex2jar from working on a React Native application. What you are seeing is the majority of React Native application logic lives in compiled Javascript files and the native layer itself (libraries).

So I would put things into 4 buckets

- Native Modules (Android - Java/Kotlin, iOS - ObjC/Swift)
- RN Bridge (Java/C++)
- JS (Virtual Machine - JavascriptCore / Hermes)
- JS (Business logic)

The code written in Javascript is interpreted by either the runtime of JSC/Hermes in the VM. This is passed through an intermediate bridge layer of either Java/C++ to the low native portion of the phone. Hence giving the name of React Native.

So if you are decoding an application looking for source code - you'll stumble upon the java code of the bridge and any package that has an intermediate dependency in Java and not the true source code of the application you are probably looking for.

The business logic would more than likely be in a `index.android.bundle` file somewhere and that will be quite ugly visually as its minified. You'll need a JS beautifier to get anywhere with this path.